# MKL or BLAS routine to multiply vector by a scalar out-of-place

Tags: c++, c, performance, blas, intel-mkl

I work in simulation software and one of the many operations done on arrays is scaling a vector by a number.

I have code like this:

```
//Just some initialization code, don't bother about this part
int n = 10000;
std::vector<double> input(n, 42.0);
std::vector<double> output(input.size());

double alpha = 69.0;

//the actual calculation:
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    output[i] = input[i] * alpha;
}
```

I have the MKL library available, so if my calculations are done "in-place" the following can be written:

```
cblas_dscal(n, alpha, &input[0], 1);
```

However, this will change the `input` variable, which is not what I want.

I tried using the `mkl_domatcopy()` but it is very slow for this operation.

Comment: You looking something which does `B <- aA` ?

Comment: Yes @111111, exactly.

Comment: `cblas_dcopy` then `cblas_dscal` or zero and `cblas_daxpy` ? Would that be slower ?

Comment: That's the solution I came up with francis. It is faster than the simple loop by a small amount, however it looks like a waste of time. But it will do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was calling `cblas_dcopy()` then `cblas_dscal()`.

It is not the best of all worlds but it is still faster than the raw loop.

Comment: Did you try cblas_daxpy with a 0 array?

Comment: I didn't, but I will try that

Answer (score 1):

From MKL reference:

The cblas_?axpy routines perform a vector-vector operation defined as

*y* := *a* * *x* + *y*
where: *a* is a scalar, *x* and *y* are vectors each with a number of elements that equals *n*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a routine within the BLAS-like extensions called [cblas_?axpby](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-axpby#005DD24D-A872-4A42-909C-5E7458191670)

Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> Scales two vectors, adds them to one another and stores result in the
>   vector.

The difference to `cblas_?axpy` is that you have second scaling parameter on the result vector y. In your case, you could just set `b := 0.0` and thus have your out of place scaling in one call, instead of the two `cblas_dcopy()` and `cblas_dscal()`.

Your code could look like this:

```
//Just some initialization code, don't bother about this part
int n = 10000;
std::vector<double> input(n, 42.0);
std::vector<double> output(input.size());

double alpha = 69.0;

//the actual calculation:
cblas_daxpby (output.size(), alpha, input.data(), 1, 0.0, output.data(), 1);
```

Comment: That looks like the perfect solution. Unfortunately I don't work at this company anymore and can't really be sure that this will be done.

Comment: I didn't know `std::vector::data()` member function to retrieve a pointer to the internal raw array, which is generally faster than an iterator. Thank you.